# How to pass HTML tags content to mark.js and separate them with a space or a comma?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, mark.js

I'm using the mark.js library to highlight keywords on a page, this works fine but I need to add an extra space or a comma after each tag h1, h2, etc..

First I thought about a loop like this, but the mark's library doesn't like it and have this error: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document':

```
    var els = document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3, p"); 
        var text = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < els.length; ++i) {
            text.push(els[i].textContent);
        }
             var context = text.join(" ");

var instance = new Mark(context);
```

So instead what seems to work is something like this where I could amend the content of each tag and add a space or a comma at the end of each tag, but I'm not sure how to achieve this?

```
var context = document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3, p"); 
      
context.forEach(element => {
  element.textContent = 'All demo classes updated.';
});
 
var instance = new Mark(context);
```

**EDIT:**

The below code works fine i.e. all the HTML tags are getting passed into mark.js without any errors. But as mentioned I want to add a space or a comma after each tag, so far I have the error mentioned above with the proposed solutions.

```
   var context = document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3, p"); 
     var instance = new Mark(context);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the javascript to:

```
var contextText = Array.from(context).map(element => {
  return element.textContent + 'All demo classes updated.';
}).join(', '); //get the text separated by comma
var instance = new Mark(contextText);
```